# Как сделать Maven проект с автоматическим применением, во время разработки, внешнего codestyle файла?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, eclipse, maven, code-style

Есть maven проект. Код в нем на java. Есть обусловленный code style, правила которого записаны в .xml файл.
Необходимо как-то сделать так, чтобы этот файл со стилем, автоматически подбирался и применялся в Eclipse и IntelliJ IDEA. И возможно ли это?

Дополнительно:
1.Про Maven Checkstyle Plugin читал, но он лишь проверяет на этапе сборки, и даже не стопорит её а выдаёт файл с отчетом проверки. Значит не подходит. Или я не правильно понял?

Answer (score 1):

В такой конфигурации сборка будет остановлена в случае наличия ошибок

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <configLocation>sun_checks.xml</configLocation>
    <suppressionsLocation>checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
    <suppressionsFileExpression>checkstyle.suppressions.file</suppressionsFileExpression>
    <failsOnError>true</failsOnError>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Eclipse ругается:
"Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-checkstyle-plugin:3.0.0:check (execution: default, phase: process-sources)"
на тэг  <execution> .

Comment: Ничего не могу сказать про Eclipse, не работаю с ним. Но Google по запросу "Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration"  выдал целую кучу результатов, в которых написано, что у Eclipse есть проблемы с жизненным циклом maven-плагинов. Возможно, [ответы к этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6352208/how-to-solve-plugin-execution-not-covered-by-lifecycle-configuration-for-sprin) вам помогут.

Answer (score 0):

Автоматически не знаю, буду следить за вопросом, а пока:

```
Ctrl+Alt+L
```

> Reformat a module or directory. Right-click a module or a directory
>   and from the context menu, select Reformat Code or press this
>   shortcut.

Нажать Ctrl+Alt+L на директории, для форматирования всех файлов. Т.е. настройте стили в IDEA и потом Ctrl+Alt+L на проекте.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/editor-basics.html

Comment: Это совершенно не выход. Это означает, если  хотя бы человек работающий на проекте, забудет настроить сам проект. То толку от соглашений по code style никакого.

Answer (score 0):

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>   
  <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <configLocation>GoogleChecks.xml</configLocation>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>process-sources</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

В итоге чтобы все работало нужно было:

1. Обновить плагин m2e.
2. найти правильный .xml описывающий правила для плагина.

Например как у Google:
https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/blob/master/src/main/resources/google_checks.xml

Что в итоге выходит:
При сборке проекта начинается проверка на соответствие правилам.
если правило нарушена, сборка прекращается.
Рапорт можно посмотреть в папке target, там все хорошо описано.